# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied: [4776] Failed to execute script docker-compose when running docker-compose up

Tags: python, windows, docker, docker-compose, permissions

I have built a test app to better understand the concepts of FastAPI and sqlalchemy
I want to be that app able to provide a docker-compose.yml that can be used to run my solution by just
doing `docker-compose up`

But I am getting

```
Building al_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1070, in up
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1066, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 615, in up
  File "compose\service.py", line 362, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose\service.py", line 1125, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 160, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 30, in tar
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 49, in exclude_paths
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\build.py", line 184, in rec_walk
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: '\\\\?\\C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18'
[4776] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

My docker file

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt 

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

ENV DATABASE_URL="postgres://superuser:superuser@localhost:5433/al-test-3" 

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

and docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  al_test:
    build: /
    ports:
     - 5001:80
  postgresql:
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:latest"
    volumes:
      - postgresql-data:/bitnami/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5446:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=al-test-3
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=superuser
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=superuser
      - POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=superuser

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

I think that there is a problem with:

```yaml
    build: /
```

To build with the local folder as context, you should say

```yaml
    build: ./
```

### What really happened ?

That being said, how is your project structured? Where is your `Dockerfile`? Is it

```
app
    - some.py
Dockerfile
requirement.txt
docker-compose.yaml
```

From the standpoint of your `docker-compose.yml`, `./` is the folder it is in. In Unix file systems `/` stands for the **root of your file system**; what you would call `C:\`.

#### At build time

I am not sure how **docker** is integrated in Windows but it might be possible that `/` is translated as some place where your docker demon does not have the right to read, raising this `PermissionError` during your compilation.

#### At run time

You might encounter similar right issues while trying to mount various folders into your container. Here is the fix (when it occurs)
[image]

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion removed the permission error, thank you so much for it!
And yeah structure is definitely as you  descrived above

Comment: Glad I could help, @VladIvanyk .